# New MMR brackets in Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

What are the new MMR brackets for SC2? How much MMR is required to reach each division?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the MMR cutoffs change too frequently to give a meaningful answer here. However the current leagues for Legacy of the Void according to [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Battle.net_Leagues#Divisions) are:

- **Grandmaster**: Top 200 players by region (1000 players total)
- **Master**: Top 4% of players by region
- **Diamond**: Next 23%
- **Platinum**: Next 23%
- **Gold**: Next 23%
- **Silver**: Next 23%
- **Bronze**: Bottom 4%

Each league is split into 3 tiers, with tier 1 requiring the highest MMR.

These numbers are approximate. Liquipedia cites [www.rankedftw.com](http://www.rankedftw.com/stats/leagues/1v1/#v=2&r=-2&sx=a) which you can check for more accurate numbers. (Interestingly, at the time of posting, Korea still uses the original distribution: Plat, Gold, Silver and Bronze each holding 20% and the upper 3 leagues holding the top 20% between them.)

Divisions, on the other hand, are mostly arbitrary:

> There are numerous divisions within each League, with each division being composed of up to 100 players. The name of each division is made up of a word from Starcraft terminology, and a letter from the ICAO phonetic alphabet, such as Gold League/ Division Zeratul Juliet. The process of matchmaking is based solely on MMR and not on a player's division or league. This means players will often face opponents from other divisions, and may face opponents from different leagues.